# My dad keeps getting all my apps that I download. why?

Tags: apple-id, iphone

My dad and I used to have the same Apple id, but recently I made his own (he didn't know how to work his) and I changed it on his phone. I kept mine on a new device. But he still keeps getting any app that I download. I don't know how to make it stop transferring all my data to him.

Comment: the phone is still tied to the original ID. Did you totally wipe it & start again, or just set up a new ID on it?

Answer (score 7):

There are a few places Apple IDs can be set on a phone. Make sure that you changed his Apple ID in his iTunes & App Store setting on his phone.

You shouldn't have to, but you may want to make sure that Automatic Downloads is not turned on also (in the same settings menu).

Answer (score 2):

Your Dad's phone is still tied to your Apple ID for automatic downloads, so any of your purchases are automatically downloaded to his phone. This is easily fixed, and can even be done without access to his phone.

You can [manage your automatic download devices with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204074). Launch iTunes (these instructions are for iTunes 12.x), make sure you're signed in to *your* Apple ID, then:

1. Click the account dropdown in the title bar, to the left of search (it'll be labelled with the first name of the Apple ID).
2. Select Account Info (you'll probably be prompted for your password; make sure you login with *your* Apple ID.
3. In the section labelled iTunes in the Cloud, click the Manage Devices link.
4. All devices authorised for automatic downloads, whether they're currently set to *receive* items or not, are listed. Remove any unwanted devices by clicking the remove button next to their entry.
5. Click Done, 'cause you are (done).

Any devices you removed from the list will no longer be able to automatically receive purchase you make with your account. If you remove a device within 90 days of adding it to your account, that device cannot be added to another Apple ID until the 90 days have passed; in this case, the device's entry will show the remaining number of days.